# where is /etc/xinetd.d/telnet in fedora 23

Tags: server, fedora, telnet

I'm studying linux server book. 
I'm now seeing telnet.

they say after install telnet, I should modify telnet configure in /etc/xinetd.d/telnet
but there is no telnet file. but install is well finished.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora 23 is based on Systemd. The Fedora 23  `telnet-server` (that's what you installed) uses sytemd service units to manage the telnetd service. To enable it, run systemctl enable telnetd.socket and to start it, `systemctl start telnetd.socket`. Use this `/usr/lib/systemd/system/telnet.socket` instead for checking configuration.

Comment: for me, "systemctl start telnetd.socket" is not worked. "systemctl start telnet.socket" is worked